emacs in a jupyter terminal
I'm using Emacs in a Jupyter Lab terminal through a browser. Unfortunately, some of my favorite commands C-s for search and C-w for cut are being intercepted by the browser and not being sent to the terminal. Has any body dealt with this before? Is there a workaround?

There is nothing that Emacs can do: it does not even get to see the keystrokes,  If the problem is that the Jupyter Lab terminal intercepts these keys, then you need to customize it not to do so, or open a request to the devs to make such keys customizable. Ditto if it is the browser, or the desktop environment, or the OS or whoever tha's doing the interception.
